# Angular 2 two-way binding propagation through components

Tags: angular, binding

I'm trying to make two-way binding in a component and propagate it through other components that contain the child component:

I have a child component, with two-way binding and it's working. The binding is pointing to a variable called `child_value`

Then this child component is present in the template of a parent component. I want a two-way binding here too, so I use `[(child_value)]=parent_value`

Finally this parent component is used in my application, so in this component I also want a two-way binding like `[(parent_value)]=application_value`

But only the first binding is working in two way. To exemplify it I created this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/IWVzmRbqL3ARFaYxjs3F?p=preview

When you drag the slider you can see that the Child value updates, but the others don't. If I change the `application_value` in code, through the button, then it is propagated through all components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. The easiest way to fix your code:**

If you check the console log that you've written into, you can see that `AppComponent` and `ParentComponent` are notified by the `valueChanged` event, all you need to do is to update the value of the variables accordingly:

In `AppComponent`:

```
  onchange(event)
  {
    this.application_value = event.value; // <-- add this line
    console.log('root::onchange() => value:' + event.value);
  }
```

In `ParentComponent`:

```
  onchange(event)
  {
    this.parent_value = event.value; // <-- add this line
    console.log('parent::onchange() => value:' + event.value);
    this.valueChanged.emit({value: event.value});
  }
```

Here's the plunker for your reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/TW2F6mdx1SJbdjKqonmO?p=preview

**2. Understand two-way binding and make it works:**

Here is the reason why the two-way binding doesn't work on your case:

> The banana in the box syntax (`[(child_value)]="someValue"`) is just a
>   syntactic sugar for having both `[child_value]="someValue"` and
>   `(child_valueChange)="someValue=$event"`.

And because you never define the `@Output() child_valueChange` in your component, the return way is blocked. To solve it:

- Change your `@Output() valueChanged` to `@Output() child_valueChange`
  in your `ChildComponent` and
- Change your `@Output() valueChanged` to
  `@Output() parent_valueChange` in your `ParentComponent`

The second plunker that has working two-way binding: http://plnkr.co/edit/M5CPqrgWJ53vBkqhVz4f?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for such elaborated answer, I was using solution 1 as a temporary patch but what I really wanted to know was why the two-way binding wasn't working, which solution 2 explained quite well!